# Read json object from server

Tags: java, android, json

Hi I am new to android programming and I am working on a project that converts a list into json object and stores it in the server and retrieves it. I am able to send the json object to the server and store it but i am not able to retrieve it. What approach should i use to retrieve the json object stored on the server?

Comment: Did you try anything? A code attempt maybe!

Comment: You'll have to retrieve and then parse the JSON data. Check out this link - http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: Well first of all you need to provide more details as well as code that you are trying. secondly the answers differs for two conditions one is you are the server side developer or second you are fetching data from third party server (e.g. facebook, twitter, etc). answer also differs in what format the response need to be received e.g. just few strings, huge data from SQL database, images, etc. So please be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You can reffer bellow class ...... call  getJSONfromURL(YOUR_JOSN_URL) and method will return you JSONObject. 
I hope this will work

```
 public class JSONfunctions {
 public static JSONObject getJSONfromURL(String url) {
 InputStream is = null;
 JSONObject jObj = null;
 String json = "";
// Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpget);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "UTF-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }
    // return JSON String
    return jObj;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve JSON from server you have to establish a connection with server first by using `DefaultHttpClient` Hope you did that. If yes, post your code and if no then have look on

www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial 
Or google it you will lot of help to parse the JSON when you have URL with you.